# On iOS do I have to show google logo if I am using their places autocomplete query

Tags: ios, google-maps, autocomplete

In my app I am using [google's autocomplete query](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically). Do I have to show "powered by Google" logo somewhere? Is it a restriction?

**Update**

I will just explain how I am using it. I have a signup form and I have multiple fields for Address 1st line, 2nd line, city, State, Zip.

When the user starts entering address in 'Address 1st line' text field, I show a dropdown/tableview with suggestions. And when user selects one of them, I populate remaining fields like city, state, zip.

**Questions:**

1. Do I have to show logo
2. Where to show the logo if yes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to Google's Terms of Service and not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to them, [yes you do](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/attributions):

> When displaying data from the Google Places API for iOS, such as autocomplete results or place name and address, there are some attribution and Google logo requirements you must comply with.
>
> The attribution and logo requirements fall into the following categories:
>
> - A Google map, if a map is displayed.
> - **The 'Powered by Google' attribution.**
> - Attributions for content supplied by third parties.

Emphasis mine. [More specifically](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/attributions#powered):

> If your application displays Places API data on a page or view without a Google Map, you must show a 'Powered by Google' image with that data.

Comment: does you answer still holds after updating my question and adding more details

Comment: Yes. From the same link: "The requirements apply to the place picker UI widget as well as the programmatic API calls." As long as you're making a call to the API, you have to give the appropriate attribution.